# setItemOnclickListener not working in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase

Im new to FirebASE and Stuck on **setItemclickListener** , here are some snippets shown please help me. Mainly struck in the FirebaseRecycler where the setItemClickListener is the interface and used for Onclick of the Firebaserecy

Leavereqests.java

```
  @Override
//LeaveReqests.java 
    leavereq= database.getReference("LeafForm");
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_hod);
    recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(manager);
    loadhod();
}
private void loadhod() {
  adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<LeaveReq, HodViewHolder>(LeaveReq.class,R.layout.hod_login_list
          ,HodViewHolder.class,leavereq) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(HodViewHolder viewHolder, LeaveReq model, int position) {
             viewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());

            clickitem = model;
            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() { //the non working part 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                    Intent hodlist = new Intent(LeaveRequests.this,HodReqList.class);
                    hodlist.putExtra("hodid",adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                    startActivity(hodlist);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);}}
```

HodViewholder.java

```
public class HodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
public Button name;
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public HodViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    name=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_of_faculty);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);

}}
```

LeaveReq.java is the class which has getter of the name.

```
public class LeaveReq {
private String name;

public LeaveReq() {
}

public LeaveReq(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Item Click Listener Interface

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
void onClick(View view, int position);
}
```

the list is being populated but the click action is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

The functions such as the **RecycleView** buttons should be placed into the HodViewHolder class so that the **RecycleView** can identify the tools that are clicked by the button

```
  //public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {..
    View mView;

    //public ViewHolder(View itemView) {...
    super(itemView);
    mView = itemView;




     viewHolder.mView .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {....}
```

I hope to help you..

Comment: where to make all these changes .. its ItemClickListener Interface Not setOnClinckListener

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<adapter, PandaViewHolder> MyAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <adapter, PandaViewHolder>(
                adapter.class,
                R.layout.replay_panda,
                HodViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase


        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final PandaViewHolder viewHolder, adapter model, int position) {

                final String position_key = getRef( position ).getKey().toString();

                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());


              //// Here
               //#################################

               viewHolder.mView.setOnClik{....}

              //#################################


            }
        };
        RecyclerView.setAdapter( MyAdapter );
    }


    public static class HodViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        View mView;
        DatabaseReference mDatabase1231223;
        FirebaseAuth mAuth;


        public PandaViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

        }

        // post text view
        public void setTitle(String title) {



        }
```

Comment: This is a simple presentation about AdAfter to display data from the ; ' ' 'RecycleView '
You can understand it and act on it